# Upsert - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, upsert

I have two tables:

1. `NewNotes`
2. `MasterNotes`

Every month the `NewNotes` table is updated with new notes for both new and existing accounts. I need to either update existing notes in the `MasterNotes` table or insert new notes if the account number isn't yet in the `MasterNotes` table.

Both tables have three columns: `REPORT`, `ACCOUNT_NUMBER`, `NOTES`.

To update a record both the account number and report have to be the same (the `MasterNotes` table can have two different account numbers with two different reports).

Can anybody help with this?

Here's my thinking thus far:

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT REP, ACCOUNT_NUMBER
FROM MasterNotes
WHERE REP = (SELECT Report FROM NewNotes) AND
      ACCOUNT_NUMBER = (SELECT AccountNo FROM NewNotes)
)
INSERT INTO MasterNotes
ELSE
UPDATE
```

I know that's not correct because the subquery returns more than one value, but I'm note sure how to go about it row by row.

Or maybe something like this?

```
INSERT INTO MasterNotes
SELECT Report, AccountNo, A.Notes
FROM NewNotes A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MasterNotes B
    ON A.Report = B.REP AND A.AccountNo = B.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
WHERE B.ACCOUNT_NUMBER IS NULL AND B.REP IS NULL
UPDATE MasterNotes
SET NOTE = B.Notes
FROM MasterNotes A, NewNotes B
WHERE A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = B.AccountNo AND A.REP = B.Report
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far! We'll be glad to be with any trouble you have - but SO isn't a *write my codez for me* service .... it takes some **effort of your own** first!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some samples to get you going.  I've provided two ways of doing both actions in SQL2005.  I prefer the JOIN methods personally, but they have been shown to be slightly slower -- but I find them easier to write/read.  They are within, but commented out.

```
DECLARE @NewNotes TABLE (REPORT VARCHAR(10), ACCOUNT_NUMBER INT, NOTES VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @MasterNotes TABLE (REPORT VARCHAR(10), ACCOUNT_NUMBER INT, NOTES VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @MasterNotes (REPORT, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, NOTES)
SELECT 'ABC', 123, 'CUSTOMER IS VERY NICE, SOMETIMES...' UNION
SELECT 'DEF', 456, 'CUSTOMER IS ANGRY'

INSERT INTO @NewNotes (REPORT, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, NOTES)
SELECT 'ABC', 123, 'CUSTOMER IS VERY NICE' UNION
SELECT 'DEF', 456, 'CUSTOMER IS ANGRY' UNION
SELECT 'GHI', 789, 'CUSTOMER WANTS CALL BACK'

UPDATE M SET NOTES = N.NOTES
FROM @MasterNotes M, @NewNotes N
WHERE M.REPORT = N.REPORT
AND M.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = N.ACCOUNT_NUMBER

/** ALTERNATE UPDATE METHOD **/
--UPDATE M SET NOTES = N.NOTES
--FROM @MasterNotes M
--JOIN @NewNotes N
--   ON M.REPORT = N.REPORT
--   AND M.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = N.ACCOUNT_NUMBER

INSERT INTO @MasterNotes (REPORT, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, NOTES)
SELECT N.REPORT, N.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, N.NOTES
FROM @NewNotes N
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER FROM @MasterNotes M WHERE M.REPORT = N.REPORT)  

/** ALTERNATE INSERT METHOD **/
--INSERT INTO @MasterNotes (REPORT, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, NOTES)
--SELECT  N.REPORT, N.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, N.NOTES
--FROM @NewNotes N
--LEFT OUTER JOIN @MasterNotes M 
--   ON N.REPORT = M.REPORT
--   AND N.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = M.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
--WHERE M.ACCOUNT_NUMBER IS NULL   

SELECT *
FROM @MasterNotes
```

NB: Should you ever update to SQL2008+, you can use the `MERGE` function as follows:

```
DECLARE @NewNotes TABLE (REPORT VARCHAR(10), ACCOUNT_NUMBER INT, NOTES VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @MasterNotes TABLE (REPORT VARCHAR(10), ACCOUNT_NUMBER INT, NOTES VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @MasterNotes (REPORT, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, NOTES)
SELECT 'ABC', 123, 'CUSTOMER IS VERY NICE, SOMETIMES...' UNION
SELECT 'DEF', 456, 'CUSTOMER IS ANGRY'

INSERT INTO @NewNotes (REPORT, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, NOTES)
SELECT 'ABC', 123, 'CUSTOMER IS VERY NICE' UNION
SELECT 'DEF', 456, 'CUSTOMER IS ANGRY' UNION
SELECT 'GHI', 789, 'CUSTOMER WANTS CALL BACK'

MERGE INTO @MasterNotes AS DST
USING (SELECT REPORT, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, NOTES FROM @NewNotes) AS SRC
    ON SRC.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = DST.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET DST.REPORT = SRC.REPORT,
        DST.NOTES = SRC.NOTES
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (REPORT, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, NOTES)
    VALUES (SRC.REPORT, SRC.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SRC.NOTES);

SELECT *
FROM @MasterNotes
```